# Overlay div linked to the same related div destination address

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I coded a linked image with overlay div:

```
<div class="imageBlock">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.twitter.com">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </a>
  <div class="overlayButton">
    Go Google
  </div>
</div>
```

Since it is a part of [Jquery Gallery plugin](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/), only one image is visible. When clicked it launches a lightbox slider.

All I need is to make the ovelay div also linked to the same image link destination as for now when I hover on the overlay div it seem to be just normal block.

Code snippet:
https://jsfiddle.net/z9mda5wv/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Your snippet code link is empty.

Comment: I think that you need an overlay button for each link, one for "Go Google", "Go Twitter", "Go Facebook".

Comment: @LGSon sorry for that, I updated the link now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest you do like this, using pseudo elements.

Clean and simple, no extra tags interfere with initial structure.

```css
.imageBlock a {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
.imageBlock a:first-child{
  display: inline-block;
}
.imageBlock a:after {
  content: attr(data-buttontext);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageBlock">
  <a data-buttontext="Goooo Google" href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/320/240/any">
  </a>
  <a data-buttontext="Goooo Twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/320/240/any">
  </a>
  <a data-buttontext="Goooo Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/320/240/any">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the overlay inside the anchor tags

```
<div class="imageBlock">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
    <div class="overlayButton">
      Go Google
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be the simplest way of doing it (no jQuery required).